# CSS background url displays with live preview of Bracket but doesn't work when open directly by Chrome or Safari

Tags: html, css

My code works and display fine on live preview of Bracket but doesn't show when open directly with Chrome or Safari.

```
HTML 
<div class="jumbotron">
    <p>we develop <span>brands</span></p>
    <a href="">projects</a>
</div>
```

```
CSS 

.jumbotron {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 665px; 
    background: url("/img/Creative/bg-final.jpg") center no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

I simply want my background image shown when open with Safari or Chrome.

Thank you

Comment: inspect and check whether image is missing or not

Comment: You don't need the quotes inside the `url()` parenthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brackets live preview creates a local server that's resolving "/img/Creative..." to the root of your project folder. When you open your HTML file in a browser, it's looking for "/img/Creative" at the root of your harddrive instead.

If you need the page to be openable in a browser without a server, you need to use a relative path. So if your CSS file is in "stylesheets/style.css", for example, you'd use "../img/Creative" to reference your image.

"../" takes you up a level in your folder structure.

Comment: Thank jmcgriz, adding "../" works. I don't know if I get it right but from what I understand, the path for url need to be relative to .css file instead of .html.

Comment: @KevinD Yes, the path has to be relative to the file that's referencing the image. So if your `.html` and `.css` files are in different folders, they'll have two different paths to the same image.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong code.
Try this - background-image: url("paper.gif");
I know you are using the shorthand code but try this.
Also always put the image in the same folder so you don't have to write the whole long address again & again.